# MS Office PowerPoint VBA Programming support or Debug Mode?

Tags: vba, debugging, powerpoint

I am trying to develop a little macro for PowerPoint using VBA. However, the "Development Environment" is an absolute nightmare!

The worst: there seems to be no real good way to generate debug output! I read that the Debug.Print output is supposed to go to the Immediate Window, but nothing appears there! So I am currently using MsgBox to generate debug messages. :-(

What's also really bad is, that errors in a macro always crash PPT. So one has to wait, until it is gone and then one has to restart it again and get rid of all the Recovery attempts. This always takes ages!

If I set On Error Resume Next it doesn't crash - at least not as often - but then things just silently don't work and I can't see what and why things go wrong (unless I plaster the code with MsgBox calls, but that requires 100'000 clicks during each execution).

And running the code in the debugger and single stepping trough the code doesn't work, either, since my macro refers to the current "ActivePresentation" and that doesn't seem to exist unless one starts the slideshow mode. So this debugging is driving me nuts!

Is this really the only possibility or environment to develop VBA code in? At least some idea re. debug output, anyone?

M.

Answer (score -1):

> > The worst: there seems to be no real good way to generate debug output! I read that the Debug.Print output is supposed to go to the Immediate Window, but nothing appears there!

At the risk of sounding insulting (which I don't intend!) do you have the Immediate window open?  While in the IDE, press Ctrl+G to see if anything new appears.  If so, that's the Immediate window.

> > What's also really bad is, that errors in a macro always crash PPT.

Not ordinarily, no.  It can happen that way, of course; your code might be triggering a bug in PPT.  Heaven knows, I ran into enough of that in PPT 2002 and 2007.  If you're using reasonable error handling and still running into errors that crash PPT, stepping through the code as it runs should allow you at least to narrow it down to the line or two that cause the crash.

> > And running the code in the debugger and single stepping trough the code doesn't work, either, since my macro refers to the current "ActivePresentation" and that doesn't seem to exist unless one starts the slideshow mode.

Again, no.  The ActivePresentation refers to whatever presentation has focus in the app, whether it's in slide show or any other view.  If your code's in one presentation and its' supposed to be acting on another, that can cause some confusion, but you simply need to switch to normal view, make sure the presentation you want to access is visible (I'd make sure not to have several in view) then Alt+F11 to return to the IDE and run your code.

All of these suggestions apply to any Windows version of PPT, going back to Office 97 (Mac?  Thinks different.  If you're using a Mac, mention that.  There are a few differences but for the most part, everything above applies except for the Alt+F11).

If none of this seems to help on your setup, it may be time to do a repair of Office.

Comment: Yes, I *do* have the Immediate Window open! :-)

Comment: @remark2: I guess my macro then must be triggering such a bug because during debugging it practically ALWAYS crashed (meanwhile I found the issue and it was simply a member of application not being present - I had copied a snippet that was supposed to run under Excel, not PPT).

Comment: @remark3: I was at first NOT referring to ActivePresentation but ActiveWindow. That yielded crashes accessing any of its members when running presentation mode (so I assume it's null during presentation mode). With ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View I got going but that worked only in presentation mode...   And I *DO* have a single presentation only, at least definitely during developing this macro...

Comment: For whatever reason: Debug.Print "..." now DOES produce output. Beats me why this hadn't worked before and I hope it stays that way. Your comment made me try again, so it has already helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, what version of PowerPoint are you working in?  If 2007, it's a bugfarm; you definitely want to apply all of the MS fixes up to and including Service Pack 3.  Then, depending on what you're trying to do, it can be easier to drill down from ActivePresentation than from the document windows/slideshow windows.  ActivePresentation will be the current presentation you're viewing in slide show view or the current one in sight in normal view as mentioned before.

Comment: I am using 2010 (in the office) and 2013 (at home). Re. the described macro they behave the same...

Comment: If you want to post a bit of code that repros the problem reliably, others can test it.